# What version of VS do I need to deploy to BizTalk 2013 R2 on a SQL Server 2012 database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am developing with BizTalk for the first time. I have created an extremely basic project in VS2103 which builds but fails to deploy with the output:

```
error DEPLOY: The database or the database version is incompatible with the installed version of this product.
```

The BizTalk installation is BizTalk 2013 R2 on a SQL Server 2012 SP3 database.

My project is using VS2013 because I understand that VS2105 can't be used to target BizTalk 2013.

There is no further information in the output window. I have a valid login on the database and can perform CRUD operations on it through VS2013.

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248697.aspx) suggests I need "SQL Server *Development* Tools" - am I right in assuming this means "SQL Server *Data* Tools" because that's all I seem to get when I search for it.

Even a pointer to where I can find a more more informative error would be useful (perhaps unsurprisingly changing the build verbosity only affects the build output when what I'd like is a more informative deploy output!).

Comment: In Visual Studio, I would go in Extension And Updates. Then under Product Updates, I would install anything related to SQL Sever. Restart Visual Studio and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this issue is related to the OS - BizTalk 2013 (or some other element of my setup) isn't compatible with Windows Server 2012 R2. Downgrading to R1 isn't an option the security team will allow. Upgrading BizTalk means upgrading SQL Server means upgrading some other software we have running on it so that's not going to happen any time soon. Looks like it's time for me to move to Azure!